# "getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None" error starting dev_appserver.py on Linux

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go, getaddrinfo, dev-appserver

I'm getting re-started with App Engine after not having used it in a while.  I'm using the 64-bit Linux Go runtime, version 1.8.1.

I believe I'm following the steps from the documentation correctly, and I believe I'm doing what's worked correctly in the past, but I'm getting this error when attempting to launch `dev_appserver.py`:

```
$ dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2013-07-11 07:24:45,919 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2013-07-11 07:24:46,230 sdk_update_checker.py:288] This SDK release is newer than the advertised release.
WARNING  2013-07-11 07:24:46,443 simple_search_stub.py:955] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.batterybotinfo.darshan/search_indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/darshan/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 182, in 
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/darshan/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 178, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 695, in 
    main()
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 688, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 659, in start
    apis.start()
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 137, in start
    super(APIServer, self).start()
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 295, in start
    if self._start_all_dynamic_port(host_ports):
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 348, in _start_all_dynamic_port
    server.start()
  File "/home/darshan/software/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 194, in start
    socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None
```

My first thought was that I might be using an incorrect version of Python.  Sure enough, I'm using 2.7.5, and [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/devenvironment) clearly states that 2.5 is necessary.  However, the documentation seems to be outdated, because after installing 2.5 and setting my system to use it, I got this error:

```
Error: Python 2.5 is not supported. Please use version 2.7.
```

Okay, so back to 2.7.5 and my initial error.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in the `dev_appserver.py` Python code (I'm guessing not, as it's been out for a month), an issue with my Python installation, or something else about my system that isn't configured according to Google's expectations.

I'd rather not mess with the `dev_appserver.py` code unless necessary, but I'm happy to poke at it to help figure out what's going wrong.  The error is on line 194; here are lines 190-195:

```python
# AF_INET or AF_INET6 socket
# Get the correct address family for our host (allows IPv6 addresses)
host, port = self.bind_addr
try:
  info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                            socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
```

I've determined that the containing method is called twice.  The first time `host` is always `"127.0.0.1"` and `port` is `0`.  The second time is the one that crashes; `host` is always `10` (an int, not a string), and `port` is a seemingly-random five-digit int.

I've tried hard-coding `host` to `"127.0.0.1"` and `port` to either `8080` or `0`, but then I get another error. I feel in over my head, and I suspect I'm not going to resolve the real issue by changing things I don't really understand.  Googling for the error message hasn't helped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Persistent Googling eventually paid off.  Despite [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688582/failed-to-start-devlopment-server-binderror-unable-to-find-a-consistent-port) having a very different (and much more informative) error message, the solution turned out to be the same: ensure that `/etc/hosts` contains only a single entry for `localhost`.

Notably, my system contained both of these lines:

```conf
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost
```

Commenting out the second (and adding a comment to document why) solved my issue:

```conf
127.0.0.1  localhost

# Having multiple localhost entries causes App Enginge dev_appserver.py to fail.
#  IPv6 not currently needed, and the dev server IS needed, so commenting out.
#::1        localhost
```

`dev_appserver.py` now starts and works properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit lines 189-194 to this, it should work until Google releases an update. This is basically just checking the type of `host` and returning early if it isn't a string.

```
189    # AF_INET or AF_INET6 socket
190    # Get the correct address family for our host (allows IPv6 addresses)
191     host, port = self.bind_addr
192     try:
193       if type(host) is not str:
194         return
195       info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
196                                 socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE)
```