# BindError: Unable to find a consistent port for localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, localhost

Sorry to be asking this again, I see it [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633881/how-can-i-solve-unable-to-find-consistent-port-localhost-app-engine-error?rq=1), but there were no answers, and I still have this problem. I did not know how to ping the question. :)

I have periodic problems running the Google App Engine development server on localhost.
I want to stress that they are periodic problems, that I have a hard time figuring out where stems from.
I am running on Mac OS X Mavericks.

I am mostly working from two locations, and it has previously been working both places, now I only have the problem in one location. I have tested stupid moves as being on wired or wireless, or even without internet.

I run

```
dev_appserver.py ShoppingList/
```

And get the following output

```
INFO     2014-10-29 20:19:40,423 devappserver2.py:733] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-10-29 20:19:40,427 api_server.py:383] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
WARNING  2014-10-29 20:19:40,428 simple_search_stub.py:1098] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/0x/6w6yzwhx28780kdnwpqdz2dc0000gn/T/appengine.husk-lige.mortenmedici/search_indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 986, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 979, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 778, in start
    apis.start()
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 170, in start
    super(APIServer, self).start()
  File "/Users/mortenmedici/Directory to extract under (this will create a directory google-cloud-sdk) /Users/mortenmedici install_dst/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 314, in start
    raise BindError('Unable to find a consistent port for %s' % host)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to find a consistent port for localhost
```

I have tried the solutions on the BindError from the other answers:
[Apps won't run on GAE - 'unable to bind to localhost:0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985130/apps-wont-run-on-gae-unable-to-bind-to-localhost0)

[Failed to start devlopment server -- BindError: Unable to find a consistent port localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688582/failed-to-start-devlopment-server-binderror-unable-to-find-a-consistent-port)
I have no other instances of the server running, I have only one localhost in my /etc/hosts and it does not help to run on a different port.

Notice that the Error is only thrown to 'localhost' not a 'localhost:0' or some specific port as in other questions. I do not know if that provide any info.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just this morning it again works at my second location. I have not changed anything but location since yesterday. I have not even shut down the mac.

Comment: And again, it does not work when I am back at my first location.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688582/failed-to-start-devlopment-server-binderror-unable-to-find-a-consistent-port)? It seems like a known bug caused by multiple entries in your hosts file for 'localhost'.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have tried that as well. Currently I have only the local host sitting there `127.0.0.1       localhost` and `255.255.255.255 broadcasthost`.

Answer (score 1):

So I've recently had this problem. Let me start by saying I did the "lsof -i :8080" to search for a process already bound to that port, yet it still kept happening.

Turns out the issue was the /etc/hosts file itself. It was empty. After populating it..it still didn't work. Only after changing the permissions to 644 did it work correctly. so...

```
    sudo chmod 644 /etc/hosts
```

let me know If that helps.