# GAE dev_appserver.py could not find search indexes on macOS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, dev-appserver

I've been trying to run a yaml file through dev_appserver.py, but it's giving me a few errors. I'm running this on the MacOS Mojave public beta and have tried a bunch of solutions such as running different hosts/ports and reinstalling the Google Cloud SDK. Here is the error it gives me:

```
INFO     2018-08-08 19:52:23,926 devappserver2.py:178] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2018-08-08 19:52:23,990 simple_search_stub.py:1196] Could not read search indexes from /var/folders/ds/3bt__b593jjbcjxg1vtqjr0w0000gn/T/appengine.None.ianlizzo/search_indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 515, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 503, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 259, in start
    apiserver.start()
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 273, in start
    super(APIServer, self).start()
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/wsgi_server.py", line 414, in start
    raise BindError('Unable to find a consistent port for %s' % host)
google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to find a consistent port for localhost
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 2183, in MainLoop
  File "/Users/ianlizzo/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 2175, in _Wait
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 614, in wait
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 355, in wait
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to start devlopment server -- BindError: Unable to find a consistent port localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688582/failed-to-start-devlopment-server-binderror-unable-to-find-a-consistent-port)

Comment: In addition to the answers in the "possible duplicate" question, you might want to ensure that `/etc/hosts` even exists, and add a `127.0.0.1 localhost` entry in case it is empty